# Move refactoring is supported only for stable object members

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I'm receiving the error message `move refactoring is supported only for stable object members` when I try to refactor / move `xyz()`, using IntelliJ 2018.2 Scala Plugin 2018.2.11

What is the reason for this limitation? As a work-around I do the refactoring by hand.

```
package package1

object TestcaseStableObjectMembers {

   def abc() = {

      def xyz() = {}

   }
}
```

Comment: `xyz` could possibly refer to arguments of `abc` and other `val`s and `def`s declared inside `abc`. So checking soundness of such refactoring requires additional efforts.